# Out of memory error while processing message in Mirth

Tags: java, mirth

Mirth service is giving the following error in one of my channels while retrieving processed messages

> There was an out of memory error when trying to retrieve messages. Increase your heap size or decrease your page size and search again.

I tried by increasing heap size but it didn't work. I was able to retrieve messages only when my page size is 5 or less. Otherwise I am getting the same error. Can anyone tell me how to retrieve processed messages without encountering this error?

Answer (score 4):

In the Mirth 3.3.1 or later versions, To increase the heap size for

**Mirth Server**

1. Go to mirth installation directory and Change the value in **C:\Program Files\Mirth Connect\mcserver.vmoptions**
   Change the Value for **'-Xmx256m'** to **'-Xmx1024m'**. This line sets the vlaues to 1GB.

EG:

```
-server
-Xmx512m
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

**Mirth Client**

1. Go to mirth installation directory and go to **Config** directory and Change the value in **C:\Program Files\Mirth Connect\conf\mirth.properties**

Change the property value for **administrator.maxheapsize** = 512m
Eg:

```
# administrator
administrator.maxheapsize = 512m
```

After these changes, please restart the mirth services.

Comment: Also you might need to increase the memory size in mcservice.vmoptions and make sure you restart the service

Answer (score 0):

What version of Mirth are you running?
What did you set the Heap size to, and where did you set it?

Have you confirmed that the increased heap size is compatible with your OS memory limit? For example, I encountered this problem on Mirth 1.8 a couple of years ago and ended up increasing the memory available to my VM (to 1.5 from 1GB) in addition to changing the heap size setting.

Comment: Using Mirth 2.2 version and increased the Mirth heap size from 256 MB to 1024 MB which is compatible with OS memory but still getting same error.

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly I am suppose to set heap size to resolve this issue?

Comment: I suppose I was asking the same question in two different ways. In Mirth 2.0+ I believe there is an option in Settings to increase it. In  earlier versions you had to modify a configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory in which you installed Mirth. From the conf directory, open file wrapper.conf. Locate the line:

wrapper.java.maxmemory=256

Increase the number as necessary, being careful to leave overhead for the rest of your server to function.

Answer (score 0):

open mirth server manager and update the server memory to as per requirement.
For me the initial value was 256 MB, I changed it to 512 MB and then to 4096 MB